# Losing Reference to UITabBarController On UINavigationController Push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Currently I'm using storyboards to segue between controllers. I have a `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` for each tab.

All my root `UIViewControllers` in their `UINavigationControllers` return the following when I log out the tab bar controller:

> Tab Bar Controller: `<UITabBarController: 0x7f7ff958d3b0>`

However when I programmatically push in a new VC in the following manner:

```
//Show New VC
UISecondViewController *secondController = [[UISecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
```

and log out the tab bar controller in secondController, I see:

> Tab Bar Controller: `null`

What's going on here?

## Update:

At first I thought it could be an issue with using multiple storyboards, but when I push `secondController` in `store.storyboard` using a storyboard segue it works perfectly. The problem is this subclass controller I'm trying to push was built to only work programmatically (third party).

Main.storyboard
[image]

Store.storyboard
[image]

Comment: How are you logging ?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Tab Bar Controller: %@"), self.tabBarController;`

Comment: Can you post anymore code?

Comment: by 'and log out the tab bar controller in secondController' do you popping the view controller from the UINavigationController's stack?

Comment: Sure. What code are you interested in seeing? The Tab Bar / Nav Controller Connections are all done on Storyboard I can post an image if you'd like? Also I push and pop from the navigation controller.

Comment: Ok, lets see what a storyboard image can show us. Also the code where you do the push/pop.

Comment: Can you subclass the third party view controller?